# Trying to add checkbox dynamically does not display the value in UI but in console it is displayed

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-grid

I'm trying to add checkbox dynamically with its value.I"m able to see the value in the console, like this  where as, it is displaying only checkbox in the page.This is my code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row text-center" >
<div  style="width:30%;"  id="cblist" ></div>

</div>

<input type="button" value="AddCheckbox" id="btnSave" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSave').click(function() {
        addCheckbox();
    });
});

function addCheckbox(name) {
   var container = $('#cblist');
   var inputs = container.find('input');
   var id = inputs.length+1;
   $('<input/>', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: 'cb'+id,class:'col-xs-4'}).html('hello').appendTo(container);     
}

</script>
```

Comment: Check the answer. Your solution should be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code, It's working.. and sure it will helpful for you..., I have used bootstape class, so it will looks fine & aligned..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .checkbox + .checkbox, .radio + .radio {
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="AddCheckbox" id="btnSave" />
            <input type="button" value="Display Checkbox value" id="displayBtn" />
            <br/><br/>

            <div class="row text-center" >
                <div class="col-md-12" id="cblist" ></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnSave').click(function() {
                addCheckbox();
            });

            $('#displayBtn').click(function() {
                displayValue();
            });
        });

        function addCheckbox(name) {
            var container = $('#cblist');
            var inputs = container.find('input');
            var id = inputs.length+1;

            $html = '<div class="checkbox col-md-4">';
            $html += '<label><input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="cb'+id+'" id="cb'+id+'">hello '+id+'</label>';
            $html += '</div>';

            container.append($html);
        }

        function displayValue(){

            $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() { //Get the only checked item
                console.log($(this).val());
            });

        }
    </script>
</html>
```

I have update some code... that shows checked input values in console....,

Comment: Hey That's brilliant!! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Oh! Welcome! It's great!

Comment: We resolved the issue,But I'm curious why I was not getting any values on the page? any idea?

Comment: For accessing the value of inputs(checkbox)... you have to use selector than get the value of specific checkbox

Comment: I have updated the answer with code new changes... I have added new button, when you click on that button, check input values shown in console..., have a look..., If any query.. let me know...

Comment: Yes,saw the updated codes.But the console.log is not diaplaying any value for displayValue.Can you check it?

Comment: Okay... Follow the steps.. 1.Add multiple checkbox.... 2.select(checked) some checkbox... than 3. click on `Display Checkbox value` button..., check your console... console have multiple checkbox values....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147838/discussion-between-hema-nandagopal-and-binary-brackets).

Answer (score 0):

You have to associate a `<label>` for each checkbox like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row text-center" >
<div  style="width:30%;"  id="cblist" ></div>

</div>

<input type="button" value="AddCheckbox" id="btnSave" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSave').click(function() {
        addCheckbox();
    });
});

function addCheckbox(name) {
   var container = $('#cblist');
   var inputs = container.find('input');
   var id = inputs.length+1;
   $('<input/>', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: 'cb'+id,class:'col-xs-4'}).text('hsssello').appendTo(container);     
   $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: 'label'+id, class:'col-xs-8' }).appendTo(container);
}

</script>
```

Notice that the label contains the `for` attribute that refers to the particular checkbox.
For your play around i have also created a [PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/wkaRgFAagbHmEiJZ6pH0?p=preview)

Comment: Yes,I tried this.The problem is,if I add label then I'm not getting the 3 checkbox in an row.Its adding in the list format.

Comment: Check the plunkr. Its just the bootstrap class i have added in checkbox and label

Comment: Let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: I still have the problem.Try to few new checkboxes, you'll find the alignment issue :)

Comment: I see the checkbox aligned properly. Please see this screencast https://www.screencast.com/t/pvyFEQqp

Comment: I'm unable to see it,Hey Are you getting 3 checbox in an row with their label?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147828/discussion-between-aka-and-hema-nandagopal).